# Eliminate Redundancy of Listing an href Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, html

How can I eliminate the redundancy created by listing an href attribute multiple times? (the only thing changing is the id name/value pair in the URL) The HTML is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="border: 2px solid lightgrey;"><iframe name="map" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="5px" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=3bee"></iframe></div>

<p><a href="https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=2c48" target="map">Do I live in Peachtree Corners?</a></p>
<p><a href="https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=270c" target="map">Voting Districts</a></p>
<p><a href="https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=ba01" target="map">Apartments and Subdivisions</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to sound rude, but I don't see anything wrong with this -- those links go to different pages and are therefore separate.  Any attempts to use JS will just complicate and confuse things.

Comment: _"(the only thing changing is the id name/value pair in the URL)"_ Note, the `.innerHTML` of each `<a>` element is also different.

Answer (score 0):

That current approach using `html` is comparatively simpler than composing `javascript` to achieve the same result. Given that each `<a>` element has distinct `.innerHTML`, using `javascript` to render the same `html` would require a greater amount of text to be written within the `document`, negating the goal of decreasing redundancy.

---

At `javascript` you can create a multi-dimensional array having value to set at `href` and `.innerHTML` for each dynamically created `<a>` element, use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate array, set properties of elements, append elements to `document`

```js
var url = " https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html";
var arr = [
  ["2c48d68065b541388e262fb4113773af", "Do I live in Peachtree Corners?"],
  ["270c6dc8c47a45b2941e286004b9da2c", "Voting Districts"],
  ["270c6dc8c47a45b2941e286004b9da2c", "Apartments and Subdivisions"]
];

arr.forEach(function(data) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url + "?=" + data[0];
  a.target = "map";
  a.innerHTML = data[1];
  p.appendChild(a);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

Comment: I see, thank you! It's just that I have several more (ten-twelve) links to add and thought it was getting redundant...

Comment: You could store query string parameters and `.innerHTML` to be set within a multi-dimensional array, iterate array, create an `<a>` element for each element of array, then call `.appendChild()` to append the dynamically created `<a>` element to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

If these are truly the **only** links on the page you can use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element.

This element goes in the head of your document and would like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://peachtreecorners.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer">
<body>
    <p><a href="/index.html?id=2c48" target="map">Do I live in Peachtree Corners?</a></p>

...
```

Keep in mind that if there are other relative urls being used on the page, that they will be disrupted by the base element.